# mySQL query returning 0 results using UNIX_TIMESTAMP

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query which I'm assuming should return results :

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    media
WHERE 
    sent < package
AND 
    flag = 0
AND 
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(last_run) + 1800 < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())
ORDER BY 
    last_run ASC 
LIMIT 1
```

I have the following row inside my DB

```
`last_run` = '2014-09-13 17:30:0'
`flag` = '0'
`sent` = '4'
`package` = '400'
```

As now it's currently `2014-09-15 02:53:57` as per the server with a `time()` of `1410749659` I assume this should be returned? if not, what's the reason behind this?

When checking the timestamps against mySQL I'm getting the following result from this query

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(last_run), UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()), last_run FROM media LIMIT 1
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(last_run)      UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())      last_run
1410752462                    1410750296                 2014-09-14 20:41:02
```

Comment: Works for me: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d98832/1

Comment: On a performance note...  performing the addition operation on the column prevents MySQL from using an index range scan operation. We typically prefer to use a bare column on one side, and do any required addition/subtraction operations on the constant side. e.g. `last_run < NOW() - INTERVAL 1800 SECOND`. But that aside, what is the **datatype** of the `last_run` column?

Comment: @spencer7593 `last_run` has a datatype of `DATETIME`

Comment: Why does `last_run` have a timestamp greater than `now()`?  Is this a timezone issue?

Comment: From those timestamps, `last_run` is `2014-09-14 22:41:02`. `NOW()` is `2014-09-14 22:04:56`

Comment: This looks like a timezone issue, since last_run is in the future.

Comment: @Barmar when I run the following Query `SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;` I get shown `SYSTEM` for both values, any idea how I can diagnose this problem

Comment: @Curtis: I recommend you test the query in the answer from Gordon, and let us know if that exhibits the same behavior. For debugging this problem, you may want to test the query after removing some of the predicates, the one on `last_run`, as well as on `flag`, `sent` and `package`. I think we're all assuming that the other three columns are all integer type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q:** I assume this [row] should be returned?

**A:** Yes, we'd expect the row you described to be returned (assuming that there's not implicit data conversions going, e.g. the datatype of the `sent` and `package` columns are integer.

With `last_run` column of datatype DATETIME, we'd expect this predicate:

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(last_run) + 1800 < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())
```

would be equivalent to:

```
last_run < NOW() - INTERVAL 1800 SECOND
```

---

The most likely explanation is that there is no row in the table that satisfies all of the predicates; the other predicates should also be investigated. (Test with those other predicates removed.)

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`.  Assuming `last_run` is `datetime`, just do:

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM media m
WHERE sent < package AND flag = 0 AND
      last_run < now() - interval 30 minute
ORDER BY last_run ASC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: If his original query doesn't work, why do you think this will work any better?

Comment: @Barmar . . . It just seemed like converting both sides could have an effect on the comparison.

Comment: This is a "better" query, in that it may give better performacne **if** a suitable index is defined. This will allow MySQL to make use a suitable index for *both* the predicate *and* the ORDER BY. But this also doesn't really answer the question that was asked. If the OP query isn't returning a row, then we wouldn't expect this query to return a row. (Personally, I'd use Gordon's query, this is the one that I would debug, not the query with the unnecessary UNIX_TIMESTAMP functions. (It's been confirmed in a comment on the question that the datatype of `last_run` column is DATETIME.)